# How do I make my rack app a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

I have a nice litte `.ru` file that I can run with `rackup` but I want to be able to publish it as as a gem. I assume I can move it to the `lib` directory and add it to my `gemspec` but what else do I need to do so that I can run just run it after installing the gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rack'
require 'illusionist'

options = {
  :Host => '127.0.0.1',
  :Port => '8080'
}

merlin = Illusionist.new

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(merlin, options) do |server|
  [:INT, :TERM].each { |sig| trap(sig) { server.stop } }
end
```

I renamed my .ru file to .rb  and then launched it with the above code. Thank you @Anton for getting me started.

Answer (score 2):

`Gemspec`+correct directory structure+(most importantly) placing a script that will launch your app(with `run`, probably) into `bin/` directory.

A little more details on gem binaries [here](http://timelessrepo.com/making-ruby-gems)

**UPDATE**

An example as requested. I have made a gem called `agent` which depends on `sinatra`(it also depends on `rack`). It has this definition of `Agent::Server`:

```
module Agent
  # Your code goes here...
  class Server <  ::Sinatra::Base

    get '/sync' do
        [200, "yahoo!"]
    end
  end
```

I also created file called `test` with following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "agent"

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run(
  Agent::Server.new,
  :Port => 9000
)
```

Then, if I run `chmod 0755 test` and `./test` after that, I can go to `http://localhost:900/sync` and see `yahoo!`.

Comment: Do you know how to write a `.rb` that will launch a `.ru` rack app? I think that's what I'm really after.

Comment: I assume that you will have to dispose `.ru` file or convert it into the form I've suggested in update to my answer. After all, your Rack application is most probably a class that can be run. Rackup command does nearly the same thing as the code I provided for `test` file with some neat features like handling parameters and providing `run` method in the scope of Kernel.